# What does `|` and `&` mean?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the syntax of these:

```
@myVar = @myVar | 2
if @myVar & 3 == 3
```

Why are they different from:

```
@myVar = 2
if @myVar == 3
```

Comment: Those are bitwise operators, not boolean operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@myVar = @myVar | 2  //bitwise or operator
```

if myVar is initially 0, this will do `0 | 2` which equals 2.

```
if @myVar & 3 == 3 // bitwise AND, and boolean compare
```

will do myVar & 3 and will check if the result equals 3

```
@myVar = 2
if @myVar == 3
```

This is totaly different, no operators (oter than =2) is aplied. So the outcome will be always the same. It alway's assigns `2` to myVar and than check if it equals `3`. You could as well have written `if 2 == 3`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: arrrggg... :-)

Comment: but why if `@myvar` is nil (undefined) before `@myVar | 2` the result is `true`?

Comment: That's because on `nil` those operators are defined to return true or false: http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/NilClass#|-instance_method

Comment: So at the end, what the difference between this and `@myVar = 2`? I don't get it. Both return 2 (if @myVar it is not null), always.

Comment: That's not the case. Take `@myVar = 12` - in this case after `@myVar = @myVar | 2` the resulting value is 14, and not 2.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to ruby, and I doesn't understand the syntax of these:
>
> ```
> @myVar = @myVar | 2
> if @myVar & 3 == 3
> ```

There are a couple of syntactic elements in the first line:

- `foo = bar` is an *assignment*.
- `@foo` is an *instance variable*.
- `foo | bar` is a *binary infix operator*, and like (almost all) binary infix operators (with the exception of `||`, `&&`, `and`, and `or`), it is syntactic sugar for `foo.|(bar)`, i.e. sending the message `|` to the object obtained by evaluating `foo` passing the object obtained by evaluating `bar` as the single argument.
- `2` is an *integer literal*.

The second line is simply syntactically invalid.

> why there are different from:
>
> ```
> @myVar = 2
> if @myVar == 3
> ```

The first line is again composed of an instance variable, an assignment, and an integer literal, the second line is again syntactically invalid.